# Filter by property of a object that is a property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, jsfiddle

I have an array of objects set up something like this:

```
$scope.people = [{name:
                  {last:"Doe", first:"John"}},
                 {name:
                  {last:"Smith", first:"Joe"}}];
```

and I'm trying to do a live filter by text box of last names.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4287/

Any help would be nice. Thank you!

Edit: sorry I put in the wrong jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your fiddle as starting point, I'd say:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
  <input ng-model="search" ng-init="search = ''" placeholder="enter search" />
  <div ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{name.last: search}">
    {{ person | json }}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{ name: { last: 'Doe', first: 'John' } },
                     { name: { last: 'Smith', first: 'Joe' } }];

}
```

Here's the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/W46Fkj

Comment: Just in case anyone sees this, there has been a change as of angular 1.2.13. instead of `filter:{name.last: search}`,  it is now `filter:{name:{last: search}}`

Answer (score 0):

So create a filter!

Building off your existing code:

```
myApp.filter("search", function() {
    return function(people, startPhrase) {
        if(!startPhrase) {
            return people;   
        }
        var filtered = [];
        for(obj in people) {
            if(people[obj].name.last.indexOf(startPhrase) == 0) {
                filtered.push(people[obj]);
            }
        }
        console.log(filtered);
        return filtered;
    }
});
```

Now, you can use a filter called "search" anywhere in the HTML. Call it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="search.name.last"/>
    <div ng-repeat="person in people | search:search.name.last">
        {{person.name.last}}, {{person.name.first}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't that a little too complex for given situation? Just saying.

Comment: I was writing this answer as you posted yours. Yours is definetely a lot simpler--I would upvote it, but I don't have enough reputation. I guess mine is a more generic to the "how do you write a filter" question.